# Flask CORS issue - OPTION request is not passed

Tags: flask, flask-cors

I spend three days to fix this CORS error but failed.
Could you please guide me how to solve this?

I configured Angular(frontend) + Flask(backend api) in the same local machine with docker containers. (Ubuntu 16.04)

**Docker#1** : flask with port 5000 exposed. 
  -> Ran with `manage.py --host 0.0.0.0` for external access.

**Docker#2** : angular app with port 4200 exposed.
  -> Ran with `ng serve --port 0.0.0.0` for external access.

The `curl --user username:password http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1/classes/` succeeded in my host PC and inside angular docker container.
Also navigate the url is OK in the chrome browser.

But I met CORS error for the OPTION when I tried to call get api in the angular code;

```
OPTIONS http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1/classes/ 401 (UNAUTHORIZED)
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1/classes/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Here's my angular service code;

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, map, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const endpoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1/';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password')
  })
};

@Injectable()
export class ExampleCRUDService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res;
    return body || { };
  }

  getClasses(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(endpoint + 'classes/', httpOptions).pipe(
      map(this.extractData));
  }
}
```

**TEST**
Below is my trials from flask side but non of it succeeded.

```py
CORS(app)
```

```py
@app.route("/")
@cross_origin()
```

```py
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

```py
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
   response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
   response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization')
   response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE')
   return response
```

```py
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/v1": {"origins": "http://localhost:4200"}})

@app.route('/')
@cross_origin(origin='localhost',headers=['Content-Type','Authorization'])
```

```py
CORS(app, expose_headers='Authorization')
```

Comment: For the workaround, I managed through apache reverse proxy configuration for the two ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am surprised that you are facing CORS issue even if you use the following:

```
CORS(app)
```

Just try follwing:

```
CORS(app, origins=['127.0.0.1:4200'])
```

I hope this will solve your issue. Let me know if you still face the issue.

Comment: Thank you Harshad Kavathiya. I'll test your suggestion soon :)